# ZKP5803 POS58 printer failing ti print with "Filter failed" message in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, printer, cups, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to install a POS58 thermal printer ZKTeco ZKP5803 in a raspberry pi 4 running Ubuntu 22.04. I updated it into CUPS as a POS58 but when I send the print I get "Filter failed" message. Can some one give me some tips to get this printer running? I will upload a screenshot of the CUPS configurations. This is the /var/log/cups/error_log:

```
E [28/Dec/2023:21:18:18 -0600] [Job 7] Unable to open raster stream - : Broken pipe
E [28/Dec/2023:21:18:46 -0600] [Job 8] Unable to open raster stream - : Broken pipe
E [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the /var/log/cups/error_log file for details.
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] The following messages were recorded from 21:18:45 to 21:18:54
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Applying default options...
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Adding start banner page "none".
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Adding end banner page "none".
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] File of type application/pdf queued by "disti".
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] hold_until=0
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Queued on "POS58" by "disti".
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] time-at-processing=1703819925
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] 3 filters for job:
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] pdftopdf (application/pdf to application/vnd.cups-pdf, cost 66)
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] gstoraster (application/vnd.cups-pdf to application/vnd.cups-raster, cost 99)
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] rastertozj58 (application/vnd.cups-raster to printer/POS58, cost 0)
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] job-sheets=none,none
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] argv[0]="POS58"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] argv[1]="8"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] argv[2]="disti"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] argv[3]="Odoo POS"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] argv[4]="1"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] argv[5]="PageSize=Custom.164.01x594.99 EPRendering=None XRXColor=BW INK=MONO SelectColor=Grayscale HPColorMode=GrayscalePrint ProcessColorModel=Mono BRMonoColor=Mono CNGrayscale PrintoutMode=Normal.Gray BRPrintQuality=Black Collate Duplex=None ColorMode=Mono CNIJGrayScale=1 ARCMode=CMBW ColorModel=Gray OKControl=Gray XROutputColor=PrintAsGrayscale BLW=TrueM job-uuid=urn:uuid:454552b5-71e2-3580-47f3-48cb5b6fd3c0 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1703819925 time-at-processing=1703819925"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00008-001"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[3]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[4]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[6]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[7]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[8]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[9]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@disti-desktop"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[10]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.4.1"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[11]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[12]="USER=root"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[13]="CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[14]="CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[15]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[16]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[17]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[18]="LANG=es_MX.UTF-8"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[19]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/POS58.ppd"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[20]="CONTENT_TYPE=application/pdf"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[21]="DEVICE_URI=usb://Xprinter%20/Unknown%20Model"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[22]="PRINTER_INFO=POS58"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[23]="PRINTER_LOCATION="
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[24]="PRINTER=POS58"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[25]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[26]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[27]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[28]="AUTH_I**"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 6215)
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster (PID 6216)
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertozj58 (PID 6218)
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/usb (PID 6219)
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] PID 6218 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertozj58) stopped with status 108 (Exec format error)
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] execv failed: Exec format error
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] pdftopdf: Last filter determined by the PPD: rastertozj58; FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE: application/vnd.cups-raster => pdftopdf will not log pages in page_log.
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] PDF interactive form and annotation flattening done via QPDF
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] pdftopdf: \"print-scaling\" IPP attribute: auto
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] pdftopdf: Print scaling mode: Do not scale, center, crop if needed
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] After Cropping: 165.000000 595.000000 164.000000 595.000000
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] OUTFORMAT=\"<none>\", so output format will be CUPS/PWG Raster
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Loading USB quirks from \"/usr/share/cups/usb\".
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Loaded 118 quirks.
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Printing on printer with URI: usb://Xprinter%20/Unknown%20Model
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Color Manager: Calibration Mode/Off
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-POS58)
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] PID 6215 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_POS58
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Calling org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device.Get(ProfilingInhibitors)
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-POS58)
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] libusb_get_device_list=7
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_POS58
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Calling GetProfileForQualifiers(Gray.....)
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Found profile /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/profiles/POS58_Gray__
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Calling org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Profile.Get(Filename)
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Failed to get profile filename for cups-POS58
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Color Manager: ICC Profile: 
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Ghostscript using Any-Part-of-Pixel method to fill paths.
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Ghostscript command line: gs -dQUIET -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dNOINTERPOLATE -dNOMEDIAATTRS -dShowAcroForm -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile=%stdout -sDEVICE=cups -r203x203 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=164 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=595 -dcupsBitsPerColor=1 -dcupsColorOrder=0 -dcupsColorSpace=3 -scupsPageSizeName=X58mmY210mm -I/usr/share/cups/fonts -c \'<</.HWMargins[14.000000 0.000000 14.000000 0.000000] /Margins[0 0]>>setpagedevice\' -f -_
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[0]=\"CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[1]=\"CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[2]=\"CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[3]=\"CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[4]=\"CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[5]=\"CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[6]=\"CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[7]=\"HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[8]=\"PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[9]=\"SERVER_ADMIN=root@disti-desktop\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[10]=\"SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.4.1\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[11]=\"USER=root\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[12]=\"CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[13]=\"CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[14]=\"CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[15]=\"IPP_PORT=631\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[16]=\"CHARSET=utf-8\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[17]=\"LANG=es_MX.UTF-8\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[18]=\"PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/POS58.ppd\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[19]=\"CONTENT_TYPE=application/pdf\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[20]=\"DEVICE_URI=usb://Xprinter%20/Unknown%20Model\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[21]=\"PRINTER_INFO=POS58\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[22]=\"PRINTER_LOCATION=\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[23]=\"PRINTER=POS58\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[24]=\"PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[25]=\"CUPS_FILETYPE=document\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[26]=\"FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] envp[27]=\"AUTH_INFO_REQUIRED=none\"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] iSerialNumber could not be read.
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Printer found with device ID: 03f0 0x0314 no-reattach Device URI: usb://Xprinter%20/Unknown%20Model
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Device protocol: 2
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Enviando datos a la impresora.
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Sent 0 bytes...
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Start rendering...
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Processing page 1...
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Error: /ioerror in --showpage--
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Operand stack:
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] (/tmp/gs_Q9xviF)   --nostringval--   1   true
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Execution stack:
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   showpage   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   showpage   showpage   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   1   3   %oparray_pop   1989   1   3   %oparray_pop   1977   1   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   1978   3   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   2   1   1   showpage   %for_pos_int_continue   1981   3   7   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   1840   2   9   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Dictionary stack:
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] --dict:772/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:81/200(L)--   --dict:81/200(L)--   --dict:134/256(ro)(G)--   --dict:325/325(ro)(G)--   --dict:33/64(L)--   --dict:6/9(L)--   --dict:6/20(L)--
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Current allocation mode is local
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Last OS error: Broken pipe
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Rendering completed
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Waiting for read thread to exit...
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] PID 6216 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) stopped with status 1.
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] Read thread still active, aborting the pending read...
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] PID 6219 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb) exited with no errors.
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] End of messages
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] printer-state=3(idle)
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] printer-state-message="Rendering completed"
D [28/Dec/2023:21:18:54 -0600] [Job 8] printer-state-reasons=none
```

[CUPS configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9zHG.png)